# Where Can I Find the "Tameable" Chocobos?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Where can I find each of the chocobos that you can tame and include in your party? Some of these make up the best monsters you can use, apart from DLC and a few other very specific creatures.

Comment: this is fine, but please close your questions about locations of individual chocobos since this one covers all the cases.

Comment: @yx The ones you find have specific requirements as they are the only two you don't randomly encounter - should they still be closed? I was waiting to give someone else a chance to answer them.

Comment: I think they should be closed, and if its closed as a duplicate it'll automatically contain a link to point to this question.  Feel free to further refine your answer with more information regarding those two if you wish.  [See here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) for some better ideas about dupes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are my findings. Note that almost all of these are rare spawns and not always easy to tame. In my experience the **Red Chocobo** was the easiest to obtain and also the first you'll have access to.

```
     Name            Growth Type   Max  Obtained                      Note
COM  Chocobo         Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Archylte Steppe ???AF
     Red Chocobo     Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Archylte Steppe ???AF    *1
     Golden Chocobo  Well Grown     40  Found - A Dying World 700AF     *2
RAV  Blue Chocobo    Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Archylte Steppe ???AF    *3
MED  White Chocobo   Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Oerba 300AF
     Green Chocobo   Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Yaschas Massif 100AF
SEN  Silver Chocobo  Well Grown     40  Found - Academia 4XXAF          *4
SAB  Black Chocobo   Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Vile Peaks 10AF
SYN  Purple Chocobo  Late Bloomer   99  Tame - Bresha Ruins 300AF       *5
```

1. *Seems* to appear most often during sunny weather in grassy sections of the map (eastern half).
2. Found in a treasure chest.
3. On the western side of the map in the marshes. Weather doesn't seem to affect his appearance or spawn rate.
4. You have to use Moogle Throw on a green orb machine in Academy HQ. Keep tossing Mog in until he finds it.
5. Only spawns in the snowy areas (not the tunnels), and *seems* to be more often when you're near a **Rambunctious Chocobo**. Watch out for **Tonberry** while searching for **Purple Chocobo**.